# Create Send-To-Compressed(zipped)-folder event shortcut on Windows10

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, compression, zip

I have a really simple question to which I haven't been able to find the right simple answer to. I'm working a lot with zipped (compressed) folders. I want to improve my workflow.

After selecting all my files that I need to zip:

`Right-click` → `Send to` → `Compressed (zipped) folder`

Is there any way to assign hotkey/shortcut for this action on Windows with only one letter for example "Z"?

So instead of doing those 3 mouse-manipulations, I only select my files to be zipped and letter "z" and it's done.

Or how to create a context-menu action shortcut on Windows10?

I want a one-letter command shortcut to perform following events:

`Right-click` → `Send to` → `Compressed (zipped) folder`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that can be down with Windows 10 out of the box.

However, if you are willing to install [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com), you could use this script to invoke *Compressed (zipped) folder* with the <kbd>z</kbd> key while a Windows Explorer window has the focus.

I've tested the following script with Windows 8.1.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass ; Only run AutoHotkey script when Windows explorer has the focus
z::                     ; Keyboard shortcut z
Send, {AppsKey}         ; Press the "context menu" key
Sleep 100
Send n                  ; Select "Send to" with the "n" key
Sleep 100
Send {Right}            ; Open "Sent to" with the "right arrow" key
Sleep 100
Send {Down}             ; Select "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the "arrow down" key
Sleep 100
Send {Enter}            ; Execute "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the "Enter" key
return
```

Comment: Thanx, man ! It worked. Except that I needed to put another first and second shortcut key cause it lauched "scan with avast" from my context menu.